# Looping back to the next column in a csv

Tags: python, loops, csv, goto, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get a script to run on each individual column of a csv file. I've figured out how to tell python which column I would like to run the script on but I want it to analyze column one, output the results, the move to column two and continue on and on through the file. What I want is a "if etc goto etc" command. I've found how to do this with simple oneliners but I have a larger script. Any help would be great as I'm sure I'm just missing something. Like if I could loop back to where I define my data (h=data) but tell it to choose the next column. Here is my script.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import * 
import pylab
from scipy import linalg
import sys
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
import scipy.optimize as optimize

a=raw_input("Data file name? ") #Name of the data file including the directory, must be .csv

datafile = open(a, 'r')
data = []
for row in datafile:
    data.append(row.strip().split(',')) #opening and organizing the csv file
print('Data points= ', len(data))
print data
c=raw_input("Is there a header row? y/n?") #Remove header line if present
if c is ('y'):
    del data[0]
    data2=data
    print('Raw data= ', data2)
else:
    print('Raw data= ', data)
'''
#if I wanted to select a column
b=input("What column to analyze?") #Asks what column depth data is in
if b is 1: 
    h=[[rowa[i] for rowa in data] for i in range(1)] #first row
'''
h=data # all columns
g=reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,h) #prepares data for calculations
a=map(float, g)
a.sort()
print ('Organized data= ',a)

def GRLC(values):
    '''
    Calculate Gini index, Gini coefficient, Robin Hood index, and points of 
    Lorenz curve based on the instructions given in 
    www.peterrosenmai.com/lorenz-curve-graphing-tool-and-gini-coefficient-calculator
    Lorenz curve values as given as lists of x & y points [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
    @param values: List of values
    @return: [Gini index, Gini coefficient, Robin Hood index, [Lorenz curve]] 
    '''

    n = len(values)
    assert(n > 0), 'Empty list of values'
    sortedValues = sorted(values) #Sort smallest to largest

    #Find cumulative totals
    cumm = [0]
    for i in range(n):
        cumm.append(sum(sortedValues[0:(i + 1)]))

    #Calculate Lorenz points
    LorenzPoints = [[], []]
    sumYs = 0           #Some of all y values
    robinHoodIdx = -1   #Robin Hood index max(x_i, y_i)
    for i in range(1, n + 2):
        x = 100.0 * (i - 1)/n
        y = 100.0 * (cumm[i - 1]/float(cumm[n]))
        LorenzPoints[0].append(x)
        LorenzPoints[1].append(y)
        sumYs += y
        maxX_Y = x - y
        if maxX_Y > robinHoodIdx: robinHoodIdx = maxX_Y   

    giniIdx = 100 + (100 - 2 * sumYs)/n #Gini index 

    return [giniIdx, giniIdx/100, robinHoodIdx, LorenzPoints]

result = GRLC(a)
print 'Gini Index', result[0]  
print 'Gini Coefficient', result[1]
print 'Robin Hood Index', result[2]
```

Comment: If you post 4-5 lines of sample data, it might be easier to test a solution.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a Gini calculator so for example say weekly salaries1 =1234,2342,2234,2121,5677,4553, salaries2=2342,23455,234,7564,43223,12213. With each salaries in a column in the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm ignoring all of that GRLC function and just solving the looping question.  Give this a try.  It uses `while True:` to loop forever (you can just break out by ending the program; Ctrl+C in Windows, depends on OS).  Just load the data from the csv once then each time it loops, you can re-build some variables.  If you have questions please ask.  Also, I didn't test it as I don't have all the NumPy packages installed :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import * 
import pylab
from scipy import linalg
import sys
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def GRLC(values):
    '''
    Calculate Gini index, Gini coefficient, Robin Hood index, and points of 
    Lorenz curve based on the instructions given in 
    www.peterrosenmai.com/lorenz-curve-graphing-tool-and-gini-coefficient-calculator
    Lorenz curve values as given as lists of x & y points [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
    @param values: List of values
    @return: [Gini index, Gini coefficient, Robin Hood index, [Lorenz curve]] 
    '''

    n = len(values)
    assert(n > 0), 'Empty list of values'
    sortedValues = sorted(values) #Sort smallest to largest

    #Find cumulative totals
    cumm = [0]
    for i in range(n):
        cumm.append(sum(sortedValues[0:(i + 1)]))

    #Calculate Lorenz points
    LorenzPoints = [[], []]
    sumYs = 0           #Some of all y values
    robinHoodIdx = -1   #Robin Hood index max(x_i, y_i)
    for i in range(1, n + 2):
        x = 100.0 * (i - 1)/n
        y = 100.0 * (cumm[i - 1]/float(cumm[n]))
        LorenzPoints[0].append(x)
        LorenzPoints[1].append(y)
        sumYs += y
        maxX_Y = x - y
        if maxX_Y > robinHoodIdx: robinHoodIdx = maxX_Y   

    giniIdx = 100 + (100 - 2 * sumYs)/n #Gini index 

    return [giniIdx, giniIdx/100, robinHoodIdx, LorenzPoints]

#Name of the data file including the directory, must be .csv
a=raw_input("Data file name? ") 

datafile = open(a.strip(), 'r')
data = []

#opening and organizing the csv file
for row in datafile:
    data.append(row.strip().split(',')) 

#Remove header line if present
c=raw_input("Is there a header row? y/n?") 
if c.strip().lower() == ('y'):
    del data[0]

while True :
    #if I want the first column, that's index 0.
    b=raw_input("What column to analyze?")

    # Validate that the column input data is correct here.  Otherwise it might be out of range, etc.
    # Maybe try this.  You might want more smarts in there, depending on your intent:
    b = int(b.strip())

    # If you expect the user to inpt "2" to mean the second column, you're going to use index 1 (list indexes are 0 based)
    h=[[rowa[b-1] for rowa in data] for i in range(1)]

    # prepares data for calculations
    g=reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,h) 
    a=map(float, g)
    a.sort()
    print ('Organized data= ',a)

    result = GRLC(a)
    print 'Gini Index', result[0]  
    print 'Gini Coefficient', result[1]
    print 'Robin Hood Index', result[2]
```

Comment: Also, you should put your comments above the line instead of inline (so it stacks on top, not adding length to each line).  There are some Python standards that increase readability.  If you're interested and have the time, this is a decent [read](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yes. That is it. I'm not familiar with the 'While true' command. But it works. Ends up I'm the user, but this is what I've been trying to do for like a week now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you choose it as the answer if it was the solution?  `while` is one type of iterator in Python; it will loop until the condition is no longer met, and since `while True` is always satisfied, it loops forever.